# SQL Server, combine tables with filling null values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables: `Customer`, `Sales`, `Detail`

- Customer table columns: `CustomerID`, `CustomerName`
- Sales table columns: `Date`, `Invoice`, `CustomerID`
- Detail table columns: `Invoice`, `ItemID`, `Quantity`

`Customer` table value:

```
CustomerID | CustomerName
-----------+--------------
     1     |    Mike
     2     |    Kavin
```

`Sales` table value:

```
Date     | Invoice | CustomerID
---------+---------+------------
2/3/2017 | 111111  |    1
5/2/2017 | 444444  |    2
6/1/2017 | 123456  |    1
6/5/2017 | 555555  |    1
1/4/2018 | 777777  |    2
```

`Detail` table value:

```
Invoice | ItemID | Quantity
--------+--------+-----------
111111  | 4      | 3
444444  | 12     | 4
123456  | 7      | 2
555555  | 7      | 5
777777  | 12     | 7
```

I want to see only `ItemID` 7 and 12, Also `Date` between 4/1/2017 ~ 1/30/2018

Result should be like:

```
CustomerID | CustomerName | Year | Month | ItemID | Quantity
-----------+--------------+------+-------+--------+-----------
    1      |       Mike   | 2017 | 4     | 7      | 0
    1      |       Mike   | 2017 | 5     | 7      | 0
    1      |       Mike   | 2017 | 6     | 7      | 7
    1      |       Mike   | 2017 | 7     | 7      | 0
    1      |       Mike   | 2017 | 8     | 7      | 0
    1      |       Mike   | 2017 | 9     | 7      | 0
    1      |       Mike   | 2017 | 10    | 7      | 0
    1      |       Mike   | 2017 | 11    | 7      | 0
    1      |       Mike   | 2017 | 12    | 7      | 0
    1      |       Mike   | 2018 | 1     | 7      | 0
    2      |       Kavin  | 2017 | 4     | 12     | 0
    2      |       Kavin  | 2017 | 5     | 12     | 4
    2      |       Kavin  | 2017 | 6     | 12     | 0
    2      |       Kavin  | 2017 | 7     | 12     | 0
    2      |       Kavin  | 2017 | 8     | 12     | 0
    2      |       Kavin  | 2017 | 9     | 12     | 0
    2      |       Kavin  | 2017 | 10    | 12     | 0
    2      |       Kavin  | 2017 | 11    | 12     | 0
    2      |       Kavin  | 2017 | 12    | 12     | 0
    2      |       Kavin  | 2018 | 1     | 12     | 7
```

I have tried many different ways, but all fail.

```
SELECT 
    CustomerID, CustomerName, 
    YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date), 
    ItemID, SUM(Quantity)
FROM
    Detail
INNER JOIN
    Sales ON Detail.Invoice = Sales.Invoice
INNER JOIN
    Customer ON Sales.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID
WHERE
    ItemID IN (1, 7)
    AND Date > '4/1/2017'
    AND Date < '1/30/2018'
```

My code doesn't work. Please help me.

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you do you need is a recursive CTE to go over the records month by month (like a month counter), starting from 4/1/2017 to 1/30/2018. Then, you adjust the output to your needs.

Here is what you need :

```
DECLARE 
    @Customer TABLE (
        CustomerID      INT,
        CustomerName    VARCHAR(100)
    )
DECLARE
    @Sales  TABLE(
        [Date]      DATE, 
        Invoice     INT,
        CustomerID  INT
    )
DECLARE 
    @Detail TABLE(
        Invoice     INT,
        ItemID      INT,
        Quantity    INT  
    )
INSERT INTO @Customer VALUES 
(1,'Mike'),
(2,'Kavin')

INSERT INTO @Sales VALUES
('2/3/2017' , 111111  ,    1),
('5/2/2017' , 444444  ,    2),
('6/1/2017' , 123456  ,    1),
('6/5/2017' , 555555  ,    1),
('1/4/2018' , 777777  ,    2)

INSERT INTO @Detail VALUES 
(111111  , 4      , 3),
(444444  , 12     , 4),
(123456  , 7      , 2),
(555555  , 7      , 5),
(777777  , 12     , 7)



DECLARE 
    @StartDate          DATE =  '4/1/2017',
    @EndDate            DATE =  '8/01/2017'

;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT 
    c.CustomerID, 
    c.CustomerName,
    YEAR(s.[Date]) AS [Year],
    MONTH(s.[Date]) AS [Month],
    d.ItemID, 
    d.Quantity, 
    DATEADD(MONTH, 0, @StartDate) AS x
FROM @Sales s
LEFT JOIN @Detail d ON s.Invoice = d.Invoice
LEFT JOIN @Customer c ON c.CustomerID = s.CustomerID
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
      CustomerID,
      CustomerName,
      [Year], 
      [Month], 
      ItemID,
      Quantity,
    DATEADD(MONTH, 1, x) 
    FROM CTE
    WHERE  
    DATEADD(MONTH, 1, x) < @EndDate
)
    SELECT 
        CustomerID, 
        CustomerName, 
        YEAR(x) AS [YEAR], 
        MONTH(x) AS [Month],
        ItemID,
        CASE WHEN YEAR(x) = [YEAR] AND MONTH(x) = [Month] THEN SUM(Quantity) ELSE 0 END AS Quantity
    FROM CTE
    WHERE 
        ItemID IN(7,12) 
        GROUP BY 
        CustomerID, 
        CustomerName, 
        [YEAR], 
        [Month],
        ItemID, 
        x
    ORDER BY CustomerID
```

Comment: Thank you. It looks like work, but there is a little problem. When I changed date range from '4/1/2017 to '8/1/2017', CustomerID 1 is fine, but CustomerID 2 shows all data like '4/1/2017 to '1/30/2018'. x <= @EndDate is affected to only CustomerID 1. hmm..

Comment: It looks like works, but if use real data, it doesn't show up correct data. it shows same data more than 20 times. I think you can't check this because you don't have big data. I fixed this issue after I added some code in Where clause. However, there is another problem about customer data. It doesn't show up customerID and Name if the customer doesn't have value. I need to show all data. By the way, Thank you.

Comment: @Teddy true, without the real data there is no guarantee with the results. About the customer that doesn't have value, it must be the JOIN. if the customer doesn't have any recorded sales on Detail table, they'll not show up, if you want to include all customers that not in the Detail, replace the from part to Customer and join the Sales table on the customerID, then join the Detail on the Sales table. If there is some incorrect results, provide the missing data in the sample and try to replicate the logic and schema of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using an aggregation function (SUM), you need a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT  CustomerID ,
        CustomerName ,
        YEAR([Date]) ,
        MONTH([Date]) ,
        ItemID ,
        SUM(Quantity)
FROM    Detail
        INNER JOIN Sales ON Detail.Invoice = Sales.Invoice
        INNER JOIN Customer ON Sales.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID
WHERE   ItemID IN ( 1, 7 )
        AND [Date] > '4/1/2017'
        AND [Date] < '1/30/2018'
GROUP BYCustomerID ,
        CustomerName ,
        YEAR([Date]) ,
        MONTH([Date]) ,
        ItemID ;
```

Comment: Thank you, but not that simple.